# Disable soft keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I have an `edittext` in my layout, like this:

```
//...    
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_username"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/string_username" >
</EditText>
//...
```

And when the layout is shown, the keyboard appears with the focus on the `edittext`, but this just happens in ICS... And I don't want that the keyboard appears automatically, just when the `edittext` is clicked.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried setting the focus to something else in onResume()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The initial state of the keyboard is configurable in your Android manifest, like this:

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possibility:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

You can also find more possibilities [in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

In your code. See: [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2611031/321697). Basically, just add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` to your Activity in the manifest. This will cause the keyboard to be hidden when the Activity is launched.