# EditText doesn't start automatically

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

In my app, I have an `EditText`. How do I make it doesn't start automatically? Like: once they open the activity it automatically sets the mouse to the `EditText` and the keyboard gets opened so they type…

Is there anyway I can make it open (the keyboard shows and the user can type) when they clicks on it?

Comment: Have you tried to set focus to it?

Comment: The exact answer as you want is [this][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so from your question i figure out that your EditText is getting focus while starting the activity. You can disable the focus using following command to suppress the keyboard.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Visit this [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1109022/996493)

Answer (score 0):

the answer by Lucifer must work. But when i got the same problem, that solution did't work, and someone suggested me this.

add a fake layout as the first element in you parent layout and make it focusable.

Like this:

```
<ParentLayout
     .....
     ......>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
    </LinearLayout>

     ......
     ......
     ......

</ParentLayout>
```

This definitely works, but the best solution is:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```