# Soft Keyboard From Pushing View Up

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a View with a `edittext` in it at top left side. Issue is that when soft key board appear it move up my whole parent view upside in which this `edittext` is present. i used the `adjustPan` and `adjustResize` and all other properties in `manifest` file but not helpful for me. I am facing this issue in a specific device.

Comment: when user tap on edittext , keyboard comes up and whole my UI goes upside that mash all things.

Comment: yeah faced same thing early just removed focus from EditText , is it necessary to have focus on EditText ?

Comment: i have no any focus on edittext but when user tap on edittext it will show up the keyboard

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1662088/1218762 , this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

and

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Let me know using both this are helpful to you or not and also use `scrollview` in the layout where your virtual keyboard is creating problem it also help a bit

Comment: These are not helpful for me : "keyboardHidden|orientation" and adjustPan. please tell me what u mean by scrollView? U mean i put my editText in scrolview ?

Comment: no. use adjust pan and put your whole layout which is distroting in a scrollview

Answer (score 0):

It might need only one property in your android manifest.xml just set "adjustPan" it think that might help,just try it.

Comment: Please make sure that in your layout of that activity should be relative so helpful,if you like to share your ui so we can make clear idea.