# Why does Android soft keyboard appear when it does?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Could anyone please explain why the soft keyboard appears and disappears when it does?

I have a layout with a bunch of different controls, mostly EditTexts and Buttons.   When I first display that page an EditText at the top of the layout has the focus and the soft keyboard is covering the bottom 45% of the screen

I assumed that the keyboard was there because the EditText had the focus, so I decided to give a button at the bottom of my page the focus instead via . . .

```
  butDone.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
  bResult = butDone.requestFocus();
```

... right after the *setContentView()*.  This worked as far as giving the button focus.   The botton got the focus and the EditText no longer had focus BUT the keyboard was still there.  Eventually I got rid of the keyboard via

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

but clearly my theory about the EditText having focus was wrong.  So could someone please explain the "rules" about what makes the keyboard appear when it does, or a link to those rules?   Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By default the first `EditText` will get the focus, if you didn't define anything about the focus in the layout's XML.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2611031/764822) answer for more information. You should use this solution if you don't want the keyboard to show up instead of dismissing the keyboard.

Comment: So are you saying that even though I give the focus to the button in the code, it ignores that because the focus isn't specified in the XML?

Comment: No, I'm just saying that it is a better solution to specify that on the XML rather than letting Android focus on the first EditText by default and then change it programmatically.