# focus of EditText in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, autofocus

I have three screens in my application, and these have 3 editTexts each screen.
My problem is that , when ever these activities are launched, defaultly cursor is going to the first edittext and keyboard is popping up .

what i want is , when the user clicks at the editbox, then only keyboard should popup.

Thanks in Advance,

Sudheer

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup

Comment: Please check stack overflow question pointed by Tushar.

Answer (score 2):

First test in your xml file that you may have this line in your edit text `<requestFocus />` remove it, and here is some example which can help you
[Example link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/name"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >

   <-- remove this line /// <requestFocus /> 
</EditText>
```

also add this in your activity

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

At your layout.xml, remove this line (at the bottom of your EditText):

```
 <requestFocus />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Add `windowSoftInputMode` in all activites it will avoid  keyboard is popping up . when you touch `EditText` that time only appear

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your oncreate() method.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        }
```