# Prevent EditText from automatically focusing

Tags: android, android-edittext, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have an Android activity and there is one `EditText` in the whole layout. For some reason, whenever the activity starts, the keyboard comes up.
I have tried **all** of the following things:

- Placing these two in `OnStart`:

  ```
  FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.searchText).ClearFocus ();
  FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.searchText).Selected = false;
  ```
- Adding a `LinearLayout` with these two properties:

  ```
  android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
  ```
- Adding the following tag inside another `View` on the layout:

  ```
  android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
  ```
- Adding this to my activity manifest:

  ```
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
  ```

But *still*, the keyboard opens when the activity opens. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: To whoever is viewing this and considering flagging it as a duplicate, please don't. I've read through [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup) and have tried everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this -`this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);`

Answer (score 7):

Try these for `Xamarin.Android` (Cross Platform)

```
this.Window.SetSoftInputMode (SoftInput.StateHidden);
```

Or

Add this to manifest,

```
[Activity(Label = "SampleApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.StateHidden)]
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved the day! No hacks, no overhead code, pure awesomeness. <3

Answer (score 2):

Add this to manifest file...

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Android by default targets the first focusable object. Whilst kirankk's answer works for standard activities, if you're using a `DialogFragment` with a custom view, the much easier option (which incidentally also works for standard activities) is to make the ViewGroup (ie `LinearLayout`/`RelativeLayout`) that your text view is contained in focusable and focusable in touch mode. This can be done from the AXML and prevents the `TextView` being the first focusable view.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old, but find that adding this to your root view in the XML file usually helps to prevent this issue:

```
 android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```