# How to hide IME when EditText is focused

Tags: java, android, wear-os, ime

I want `EditText` not to extend IME when it is focused on Android Wear.
I read and implemented in the same way as the following thread:
[Prevent EditText from automatically focusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407505/prevent-edittext-from-automatically-focusing)

However, IME appears.
Is it impossible to hide IME for an `EditText` on Android Wear?

I tried 3 methods:

1. Added the following code in the onCreate() method:

   ```
   {getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);}
   ```
2. Added the following code in the activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
   ```
3. Added the following code in rect_activity_main.xml

   ```
   <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
   android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
   ```

None of them worked.

Best regards, gellpro

Comment: Check this one..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429595/how-to-stop-the-android-soft-keyboard-from-ever-coming-up-in-my-entire-applicati

Answer (score 0):

Check [Show the Input Method On Demand](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html#ShowOnDemand). It's noted that the system hides the input method when the user finishes the task in the test field or the user can hide it with a system control. With this, try to [specify how your UI should respond](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html#Respond). It's mentioned that,

> To declare your preferred treatment in an activity, use the `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute in your manifest's  element with one of the "adjust" values.

Then, to implement hiding IME, try using [InputMethodManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) with constant set to `RESULT_UNCHANGED_HIDDEN`. This will flag for the `ResultReceiver` result code from `showSoftInput(View, int, ResultReceiver)` and `hideSoftInputFromWindow(IBinder, int, ResultReceiver)`: the state of the soft input window was unchanged and remains hidden.

Hope that helps.