# Hide keyboard when showing DialogFragment on tablet?

Tags: android, keyboard, show-hide, dialogfragment

I am using `DialogFragment` with `ListView` (to list all customer) and `EditText` (to search from list), it's working fine.  But, whenever the dialog shows from the fragment, the keyboard is always shown and the user needs to resign. Is there any way to hide this at the first time while showing the dialog fragment? then, when the user clicks on edit text, the keyboard should appear.

I have tried setting `android:focusable="false"` in my XML but, it always hides the keyboard after click on `EditText` also not showing.

Then I tried setting `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` but, getting same as above

Comment: Have a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup

Comment: thanks friends will check it and let u know @Ganesh

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your DialogFragment onCreateView() add the following:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
 View view = super.onCreateView( inflater, container, savedInstanceState );
 //to hide keyboard when showing dialog fragment
 getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
 return view;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I had seen all the other posts that just dealt with activities and no matter where I put it when dealing with fragments it did not work.. getDialog() vs getActivity() was the key for me. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work when the dialog is a `DataPickerFragment` in Android 4.4, and I put the hide keyboard method in the `onResume()` method and it works. Anyway, thx.

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

or

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"
```

Answer (score 0):

use this method, it works for me:

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
        try {
            View windowToken = getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getDialog().getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow( windowToken.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:If you want close keyboard on open of dialog fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
 View view = super.onCreateView( inflater, container, savedInstanceState );
 //to hide keyboard when showing dialog fragment
 getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
 return view;
}
```

case 2:If you want close keyboard on selection autocompletetext or any other edit text view use simple

```
 public static void hideDialogFragmentKeyboard(Context context,View view) {
        view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }, 100);
    }
```

I think this will work