# Android Scrollview Automatically scrolling up

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scroll, scrollview

I have a layout with a scrollview and a relative layout inside of the scrollview. I have toggle buttons radio groups and edittext inside this scrollview. The issue I am having is that when I start scrolling down and selecting the toggle buttons, after selection the screen scrolls up automatically to the top. Why is this happening?

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@layout/grad_col_bk"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.91"
    android:background="@color/darker_grey" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_rel_search_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/salinityToggleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textOff="Salinity"
            android:textOn="Salinity " />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radgroupsal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/salinityToggleButton"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/salGreat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedSalinityGreater"
                android:text="Greater Than" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/salLess"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedSalinityLess"
                android:text="Less Than" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/salabove"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radgroupsal"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/salinityValue"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/salinityToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/salinityToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
        </EditText>

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/AmmoniaToggleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/salabove"
            android:textOff="Ammonia"
            android:textOn="Ammonia " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ammoniaSearchNumber"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/AmmoniaToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/AmmoniaToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/salinityValue"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp" >
        </EditText>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radgroupamm"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/AmmoniaToggleButton"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/ammGreat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedAmmoniaGreater"
                android:text="Greater Than" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/ammLess"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedAmmoniaLess"
                android:text="Less Than" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/ammabove"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radgroupamm"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <!-- split below is nitrite -->

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/NitriteToggleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ammabove"
            android:textOff="Nitrite"
            android:textOn="Nitrite " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nitriteValue"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/NitriteToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/NitriteToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
        </EditText>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radgroupnitri"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/NitriteToggleButton"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/nitriGreat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedNitriteGreater"
                android:text="Greater Than" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/nitriLess"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedNitriteLess"
                android:text="Less Than" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/nitriabove"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radgroupnitri"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <!-- Nitrate Below -->

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/NitrateToggleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nitriabove"
            android:textOff="Nitrate"
            android:textOn="Nitrate " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nitrateValue"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/NitrateToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/NitrateToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
        </EditText>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radgroupnitra"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/NitrateToggleButton"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/nitraGreat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedNitrateGreater"
                android:text="Greater Than" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/nitraLess"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedNitrateLess"
                android:text="Less Than" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/nitraabove"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radgroupnitra"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <!-- pH Below -->

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/phToggleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nitraabove"
            android:textOff="pH"
            android:textOn="pH " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phValue"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/phToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/phToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
        </EditText>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radgroupph"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/phToggleButton"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/phGreat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedPhGreater"
                android:text="Greater Than" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/phLess"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedPhLess"
                android:text="Less Than" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/phabove"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radgroupph"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <!-- Calcium Below -->

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/calciumToggleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/phabove"
            android:textOff="Calcium"
            android:textOn="Calcium " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/calciumValue"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/calciumToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/calciumToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
        </EditText>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radgroupcalcium"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/calciumToggleButton"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/calciumGreat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedCalciumGreater"
                android:text="Greater Than" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/calciumLess"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedCaliumLess"
                android:text="Less Than" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/calciumabove"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radgroupcalcium"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <!-- Phosphate Below -->

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/phosphateToggleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/calciumabove"
            android:textOff="Phosphate"
            android:textOn="Phosphate " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phosValue"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/phosphateToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/phosphateToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
        </EditText>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radgroupphosphate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/phosphateToggleButton"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/phosphateGreat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedPhosphateGreater"
                android:text="Greater Than" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/phosphateLess"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedPhosphateLess"
                android:text="Less Than" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/phosphateabove"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radgroupphosphate"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <!-- temperature below -->

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/temperatureToggleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/phosphateabove"
            android:textOff="Temperature"
            android:textOn="Temperature " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/temperatureValue"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/temperatureToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/temperatureToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
        </EditText>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radgrouptemperature"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/temperatureToggleButton"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/temperatureGreat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedTemperatureGreater"
                android:text="Greater Than" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/TemperatureLess"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedTemperatureLess"
                android:text="Less Than" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/temperatureabove"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radgrouptemperature"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <!-- Alkalinity Below -->

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/alkalinityToggleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/temperatureabove"
            android:textOff="Alkalinity"
            android:textOn="Alkalinity " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/AlkalinityValue"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/alkalinityToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/alkalinityToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
        </EditText>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radgroupalkalinity"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/alkalinityToggleButton"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/alkalinityGreat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedAlkalinityGreater"
                android:text="Greater Than" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/AlkalinityLess"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedAlkalinityLess"
                android:text="Less Than" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/alkalinityabove"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radgroupalkalinity"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <!-- Magnesium Below -->

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/magnesiumToggleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/alkalinityabove"
            android:textOff="Magnesium"
            android:textOn="Magnesium " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/MagnesiumValue"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/magnesiumToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/magnesiumToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
        </EditText>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radgroupmagnesium"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/magnesiumToggleButton"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/magnesiumGreat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedMagnesiumGreater"
                android:text="Greater Than" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/MagnesiumLess"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedMagnesiumLess"
                android:text="Less Than" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/magnesiumabove"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radgroupmagnesium"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <!-- TDS below -->

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tdsToggleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/magnesiumabove"
            android:textOff="TDS"
            android:textOn="TDS " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tdsValue"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tdsToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tdsToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
        </EditText>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radgrouptds"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tdsToggleButton"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/tdsGreat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedTdsGreater"
                android:text="Greater Than" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/tdsLess"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedTdsLess"
                android:text="Less Than" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/tdsabove"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radgrouptds"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <!-- Iodine below -->

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/iodineToggleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tdsabove"
            android:textOff="Iodine"
            android:textOn="Iodine " />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/iodineValue"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/iodineToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iodineToggleButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
        </EditText>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radgroupiodine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/iodineToggleButton"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/iodineGreat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedIodineGreater"
                android:text="Greater Than" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/iodineLess"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClickedIodineLess"
                android:text="Less Than" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/iodineabove"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radgroupiodine"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <!-- Search button below -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/iodineabove"
            android:text="Search" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I would think that one of your vertically topmost Views (probably an EditText) is receiving focus after you click the ToggleButtons. You might check this question: [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup).

Answer (score 15):

This happens because one of the views on top takes focus.
Just add

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

to the child of your ScrollView.