# why does my android keyboard opens automatically?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, keyboard

I have this Layout.
every time it's opened, the android keyboard appears

why is that?

how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your manifest file, You can avoid that.

```
    <activity
        android:name="Your_Activity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `EditText` has `requestFocus`,then keyboard might display automatically. It has nothing to do with your xml code.

Add the following line to your Manifest File inside each Activity tab

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

or add the following to your parent layout in that activity

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange ! I thought Screen which has editText only get focus.

Try this => [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Answer (score 0):

Android opens the OnScreenKeyboard automatically if you have an EditText focussed .

You can prevent that by adding following into your Activity's onCreate method.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```