# How to remove autofocus on searchBar on android when a Table data is append on scrolling

Tags: android, titanium

In my Android app I add `SearchBar` in headerview of `TableView`.

Problem is that when I scroll my `TableView` to load more data then my `SearchBar` automatically focus and table scroll to top.

I want to stop this auto focus. How do I do that?

Comment: edittext.clearFocus(); try this

Comment: searchBar.clearFocus() not found, clearFocus work on textfield but it is a searchBar

Comment: searchBar is which widget ?

Comment: edittext.clearFocus not working for me

Comment: please post your search bar layout code

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this links it will help you, [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup/1612017#1612017) , [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup/2611031#2611031) and http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/134140/how-to-stop-android-textfield-from-auto-focusing

Comment: Thanks for reply , But I can't understand how to stop autoFocus of searchBar and what to write in androidManifest.xml file ,Can you write some code to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with the keyboard opening when the search field had initial focus.
Using this code stops the keyboard from showing (even when scrolling), but when you tap the search bar the keyboard then appears.

```
if (OS_ANDROID) window.windowSoftInputMode = Ti.UI.Android.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN;
```