# android - hint text hides when activity runs on android 2.3

Tags: android, android-edittext

this is a bug I thing , I've a form , the first element is an edittext , It has a hint text .

on android 4 it's ok but on android 2.3 , when the activity runs , the hint text is gone because edittext got the focus .

so , the text is hide and users don't know what is this edittext

is there anyway to solve this ?

thanks

Comment: have my answers solved your problem

Comment: do have a check and don't forget to vote

Answer (score 1):

you can add a focusable linearlayout as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup). Add this linearlayout as first view in root layout of your form's layout xml.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="0px"/>
```

This will stop Edittext getting the focus on activity launch and so user can click to open keyboard on that after reading the hint.

Comment: thanks for the reply , it changes the focus but the problem not solved. I've searched alot and found the problem

Comment: so were you able to fix the problem or not?

Answer (score 1):

**programatically**

```
edttextid.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
edttextid.setFocusable(true);
```

through Layout XMl

```
android:Focusable="true"
android:FocusInTouchMode="true"
```

Hope it may help you

Answer (score 0):

after lots of searches ,I found the problem .

the problem is from edittext and you should add android:ellipsize="start"  to edittext in xml , it solves my problem

Comment: Not sure, if that is the right solution though, ellipsize property is for cases where the text is longer than the width of the view and you'd like to truncate the text (start, middle, end). Just my two cents.