# android EditText, remove focus when clicking another object

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Can anyone help me, Im beginner in android development, EditText is always focused, and i want to remove focus when clicking any other object, for example, ListView, Button...
i want EditText to focus only when user clicks onto it

Comment: Have you tried requestFocus() on other object?

Comment: You can use View.clearFocus() call in addition to this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/1662088/527759

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using clearFocus() method on EditText..

```
EditText txt;
txt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.somename);

txt.clearFocus();
```

Or you can use

```
 private void hideDefaultKeyboard() {
       activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);//u     have got lot of methods here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No object is focused by default so check your **XML layout file** and ensure you do not have `<requestFocus />` set on `EditText` in subject. If so, remove it from XML file - you may also want to check for `requestFocus()` calls, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

make sure there is no request focus in your layout
and adding this might help

android:focusable="false"
   android:clickable="false"