# SearchView show as always

Tags: android, searchview

i use widget SearchView

```
    <SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     />
```

its work fine , but if search box show up, i always have to click on search icon then. so can anyone help me to make search box show up without click on search icon

[image: search button]

[image: search box]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the attribute

```
android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
```

to the `SearchView` definition.

You can add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` to the activity in the manifest file to prevent the keyboard from displaying; but before you do, think about this: If the user is forced to touch the widget to display the keyboard and enter something, you might as well leave the searchview iconified so that the user can see more of the display underneath.

If you really want to remove focus, there are a few alternatives, see this post: [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Comment: when i add that attribute , searchview always focus and show keyboard when i start activity, how can i clear focus of search view