# How do I make sure the moment my search view loads keyboard doesnt popup?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-search

I am using an edittext in xml for search box. I load searchbox as soon as I call the drawer and my keyboard popsup. I would like to make it such that unless the searchbox is touched, keyboard doesnt popup. How do I go about it?
Here's my code so far:

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/search_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/searchbox"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:hint="Search"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:paddingTop="5sp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
```

corresponding class:

```
    EditText inputSearch;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        inputSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.search_text);

}
```

ant clues? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution is to either make sure another element has focus, or to clear the focus in `onResume()`. Here is a similar question on the topic: [Stop EditText From Gaining Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup). You can do this by creating another empty element and setting the attributes `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` And you can clear the focus simply by calling [`clearFocus()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearFocus()) on your `EditText`.

Comment: Based on your code, you should be able to call `inputSearch.clearFocus()` in your `onResume()` method. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in onCreate

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)
```

or

go to your application manifest file, and write this line for that activity you want to disable auto keyboard pop-up.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```