# How to remove focus from edittext after setting sometext intially in programmatically?

Tags: android, date, android-edittext

I have an edit-text for date, and I am setting today's date as default date programmatically by, and I am opening a date-picker when focus changes, So here date-picker is opening when user opens the fragment, but I want to close it for the first time, How to achieve that?. Help me

date.setText(dateFormatter.format(new Date()));

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Comment: this is not duplicate, I treid that one, Here I'm setting text to edittext after activity starting, so edittext gains focus automatically, but I want to remove that.

Comment: did you tried setting focus to some other view after setting text to your edit text?

Comment: I tried that it's working fine in that case, but here if the edittext is in one of the fragment of navigation drawer. If you just open and close navigation drawer, it is getting focus again. May I know how to achieve that?

Comment: whenever the nav. drawer opens try setting request focus to some other view everytime

Comment: how to do that? sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved it by removing focus when ondrawerClosed being called by navigation drawer

```
//In activity or fragment where we have navigation drawer
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            interfaceListener.removeFocus();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };
```

//In fragment

```
public void removeFocus(){
    editext.clearFocus();
    anotherLinearLayout.requestFocus();
}
```