# How to clear the Focus of the First Edittext in TextInputLayout which is automatically focussed and opens keyboard in android?

Tags: java, android

I have an Activity. And its Layout is as below.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_profile_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layEdtEmails"
            style="@style/edittextStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
                style="@style/edittextStyleHint"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLength="50"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true">
            </EditText>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">               

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layEdtPasswords"
                    style="@style/edittextStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
                        style="@style/edittextStyleHint"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:maxLength="15" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that, the First `editText` gets Automatically focussed when Activity Starts. I want to clear that focus when activity starts. In xml of `editText` I tried to put focusable as false. But it affects my further coding.

Comment: Inside the Edittext use the     android:cursorVisible="false"

Comment: Not working. Only cursor gets invisible. But Floatable hint moves up

Comment: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Comment: try with `stateAlwaysHidden` also.

Comment: Thanks Lucius. It worked

Answer (score 0):

Add the `android:focusable="true`" and  `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` elements in the parent layout of EditText.