# EditText hint should not hide until we touch the edittext in an Activity

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, focus

In below given image username hint never ever shown when I open this sign-in page, also tried to focus out. But that can not help me out. Please find this.

[image]

Here's my `EditText` code:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/mobile_id_signin" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="45dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_shape_wight" 
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/signin_username" 
    android:drawablePadding="15dp" android:gravity="left|center" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" 
    android:hint="UserName />
```

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: Do you mean that edittext is not showing hint?

Comment: <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mobile_id_signin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_shape_wight"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/signin_username"
                android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                android:gravity="left|center"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
                android:hint="UserName  />

Comment: error should be in "edittext_shape_wight" file. Please share code of this file

Comment: Yeah..! @kapil thadani

Comment: this is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item   android:left="-5dp"
        android:right="-5dp"
        android:top="-15dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/wight" />
        </shape>

        <padding
            android:bottom="50dp"
            android:left="50dp"
            android:right="50dp"
            android:top="50dp" />

    </item>
</layer-list>

Comment: Please use the 'edit' button towards the bottom-left of your screen to add more relevant info.

Comment: actually i am using the same edittext_shape_wight in password field..It works fine

Comment: Sorry... Can't get  you @ Shaishav

Comment: set the hint (textColorHint) color.

Comment: @Pawanpreet  also checked out

Comment: but still its hard to find:-(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Answer (score 0):

add this code in root layout because your activity gaining automatic focus on start

```
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it is working and show proper hint.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/mobile_id_signin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="45dp" android:drawablePadding="15dp"
    android:gravity="left|center" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" android:hint="@string/user_name" />
```

Comment: add hint in string file