# EditText Focus disable Android

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, focus

there are two rows one is with textview which is used as datepicker and the second one is edittext, Now my problem is when the activity is open automatically the edittext is keep focusing how to disable the focus from that.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Comment: Cant get you..Actually it is my edittext @MikeM

Comment: I don't understand what your comment means.

Comment: Your question is already answered in many posts. Please [check this post->](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Comment: Sorry @MikeM. my query is about not to hiding softkey board.. cursor should be blink @ second  row in the field of edittext..

Comment: No @musica.. I tried with that.. but it couldn't helped:-(

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, at this point. You'll need to [edit] your question to better explain exactly what it is you want, and how your current setup isn't doing that. Also, please don't make your whole question one big link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in onCreate() :

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {

        // Check if no view has focus:
        try {
            View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
            if (view != null) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //
        }
    }
```

Comment: for that i used in ManiFest file   _ android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"_

Answer (score 0):

put this line in your manifest under your activity
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"

Answer (score 0):

add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|stateAlwaysHidden"` in your activity tag in manifest file