# Edit text focus issue

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I have a activity , in a activity one edit text having some hint text.

when i start activity by default focus gone on edit text and hint invisible.

please tell me how to make hint visible

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Answer (score 1):

Add in the page an empty view:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:focusable="true" 
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
  android:layout_width = "0dp"
  android:layout_height = "0dp"/>
```

This view will gain the focus and prevent `EditText` from getting it

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in onCreate before setContentView()

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

also if you have requestFocus in xml part then remove it

Answer (score 0):

After setContentView():

```
KeyListener keyListener = new TextKeyListener(TextKeyListener.Capitalize.CHARACTERS, false);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
setInput(YOUR_EDIT_TEXT, keyListener, imm);
```

setInput method:

```
private void setInput(EditText _editText, KeyListener keyListener, InputMethodManager imm){
_editText.setKeyListener(keyListener);
if (_editText.isFocusable()) {
    _editText.setFocusable(true);
    _editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    _editText.requestFocus();
}

_editText.setSelection(_editText.getText().length());
imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(_editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```