# Focus/click on recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I got a Recyclerview and a EditText in my layout.

When I click outside the EditText (i.e clicks on the Recyclerview) I want the Recyclerview to get focus and the EditText view to loose focus. I cant get this to work. If I put a empty FrameLayout above the Recyclerview everything works as expected but I cant scroll the Recyclerview. Why cant I set the Recyclerview to be clickable and focusable?

I set these attributes in my layout xml

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="auto"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:focusedByDefault="true"
```

on my Recyclerview/FrameLayout.

Comment: Set focus: The framework will handled moving focus in response to user input. To force focus to a specific view, call requestFocus()

Comment: try  android:focusable="true" also

Comment: Try this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your xml tags have no effect is how Android handles clicks. Every event goes through the view hierarchy of the layout. First, the very top level parent of the layout receives the event. If the top level layout does not handle the event, then it gets passed to the child under it and so on.

In your case the touch event is first sent to the FrameLayout and since it is handled, the event doesn't reach the RecyclerView and therefore you cannot scroll.

The correct way to handle touch is to set [onTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) on both the RecyclerView and the child view. The `onTouch` on the RecyclerView is called first. You handle all your analyzing there (you can check x and y and also see if the touch falls inside a child view. you can also change the focus of each view dynamically).

If you don't want the child to also handle the touch `return true;`. Otherwise `return false;` and the touch event will trigger the onTouchListener of the child view.

Comment: I did this: recyclerview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                hideKeyboard(edittext);
                edittext.clearFocus();
                return false;
            }
        });

Comment: public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }