# How to disable editing in EditText on start, then enable it back when the user clicks on the EditText?

Tags: java, android

My app contains an `EditText` object with some text in it. When the activity opens I don't want this `EditText` to be editable (view only, no blinking cursor & no keyboard pop up). Then in order to edit, the user clicks on the `EditText` (This brings back the blinking cursor and the keyboard pops up).
There should have been a function like `setEditable(boolean)`. The editable XML attribute in `EditText` is deprecated (The warning suggests using `setInputType()` instead).

**Is there a way to achieve this?**

Final note: I have searched the internet for couple hours and this is the best I ended up with:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...

editor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteEditText);
editor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editor.setInputType(
                EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES | EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
    }
});

editor.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL);

...
}
```

This doesn't work as I intend. I have to double click in order to be able to edit (On first click the blinking cursor and the keyboard don't appear, in second click they do)

Comment: You could just make sure the EditText doesn't get focus first when the activity resumes/starts and whenever the EditText is tapped it will get focus and function as normal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this in your parent tag of the XML and you are done.

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

But the basic idea is to stop child views getting focus before anything else. So just give focus to the parent view group before the child.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
  android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/noteEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="30" >
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you that did exactly what I wanted.