# Automatic Scroll Down when focused on TextInputEditText

Tags: android, kotlin

So far I have done:

**MainActivity:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val email: EditText = this.findViewById(R.id.edt_mail)
    val pass: EditText = this.findViewById(R.id.edt_password)
    val scrollView = findViewById<View>(R.id.nestedScrollView) as ScrollView
    email.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            scrollView.postDelayed({
                scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)
            }, 1200)
        }
    }
    pass.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            scrollView.postDelayed({
                scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)
            }, 1200)
        }
    }}}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="258dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/companyLogo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.515"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/LoginGuideLine"
        style="@style/LoginGuideLine"
        android:layout_width="295dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/LoginGuideLine"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.518"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/edtl_login"
        style="@style/TextInput"
        android:layout_width="295dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.518"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/LoginGuideLine">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_mail"
            android:layout_width="295dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:hint="@string/EmailHint"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/edtl_password"
        style="@style/TextInput"
        android:layout_width="295dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.518"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtl_login">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_password"
            android:layout_width="295dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:hint="@string/PasswordHint"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LoginBtn"
        style="@style/PrimaryBtn"
        android:layout_width="295dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text="@string/BtnTxt"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.518"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtl_password" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="constraints">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</application>
```

This is basically a Login Page UI that I am making where I want to the screen to scroll down automatically when focused on either email or password field. On email field, it does the job but on the password field, it shifts the focus automatically back to Email field and I have tried to reset the focus but that doesn't seem to work as well so I am not sure where the issue is.

Comment: I think your `email` EditText is getting default focus. try https://stackoverflow.com/a/1662088/3758972

Comment: Tried the methods you suggested on the above link none of them works as I want them to work.

Comment: Still looking for the solution.