# Hide keyboard automatically when navigating between fragments

Tags: android

First of all this question is not about [how to hide keyboard programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard?rq=1).

We all know that we can get keyboard to [appear automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup) for `EditText` by getting focus on start and `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"`.

**Question**: I have an `EditText` in a `Fragment` being focused and keyboard is shown. I navigate to another `Fragment` and the keyboard remains shown. How can i get the keyboard to hide automatically when the `EditText` (that the keyboard is for) is no longer visible?

Yes i could have hide the keyboard programmatically but i can't shake off the feeling that there must be a way to dismiss the keyboard automatically when it can be shown automatically.

Comment: are you talking about edittext visibility  ? or you want when fragment is finished?

Comment: @quicklearner i am talking about keyboard being automatically dismiss when `EditText` is "no longer visible on screen" in a very loose sense. Technically it can be due to a variety of reason 1) visibility set to `INVISIBLE`, 2) visibility set to `GONE`, 3) `EditText` no longer in view hierarchy (e.g. fragment finish), 4) `EditText` goes out of screen (e.g. scrollview).
I am interested in any ways that Android framework can handle some/all of these scenario.