# Searchview Iconified without Focus

Tags: android, searchview

I Have created a Searchview in android. I want to keep the hint text along the search icon so I have set in xml as

```
app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
```

It solves my problem. But it takes the focus when entering to the activity which will trigger the keyboard. Now I want to keep the hidden when entering to activity.

Is there any default solution, other than creating searchview through EditText??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **intended** behavior, when `View` is created the first **focusable** `View` get the focus, however you can create a dummy object to intercept the focus. Easiest solution is to simply add this to the **root view** of your `layout`:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

P.S: what these lines of code do it to make your **root** layout `focusble` and set the focusability of the `View` before it's **descendants** so it intercept the focus **before** moving to **child** views.