# Is there a way to make the EditText always in focus without touched?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm newbie in Android and I have some problems with my code.

I want to create a **Portable Data Terminal** for my final exam in college,

**Problem,**

I don't know how to make the EditText in Android Studio always focus, I mean, when I scan the barcode using an extended scanner, the scanner sending some barcode to EditText in the apps, the scanner comes with enter key, and after enterkey pressed/clicked the data move to database and The EditText still focus for next scan, but in the real after enterkey clicked the EditText lost the focus

I've tried using `EditText.requestFocus()` but it doesn't work,

**Code**

```
PluCode.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {  

  @Override

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && (keyCode == 
KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){

               DBAdapter dbAdapter = new 
DBAdapter(getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);
                String kodetoko = StoreCode.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String plutoko = PluCode.getText().toString();
                String qtytoko = Qty;
                TransactionModel transactionmodel = new 
TransactionModel(kodetoko,plutoko,qtytoko);

                dbAdapter.onOpen();
                dbAdapter.insertTransaction(transactionmodel);
                Cursor cursor = dbAdapter.showAllData2();
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                TableLayout tablelayouttransaction = 
(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.transactionTableLayout);
                int childCount = tablelayouttransaction.getChildCount();

                // refresh row
                if (childCount > 0) {
                    tablelayouttransaction.removeViews(0, childCount);
                    int countrow = tablelayouttransaction.getChildCount();
                    if(countrow == 0){
                        do {
                            TableRow row = (TableRow) 
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_row_transaction, null);
                            ((TextView) 
row.findViewById(R.id.idkodetoko)).setText(cursor.getString(0));
                            ((TextView) 
row.findViewById(R.id.idplu)).setText(cursor.getString(1));
                            ((TextView) 
row.findViewById(R.id.idqty)).setText(cursor.getString(2));
                            tablelayouttransaction.addView(row);

                        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

                    }
                }else{
                    do {
                        TableRow row = (TableRow) 
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_row_transaction, null);
                        ((TextView) 
row.findViewById(R.id.idkodetoko)).setText(cursor.getString(0));
                        ((TextView) 
row.findViewById(R.id.idplu)).setText(cursor.getString(1));
                        ((TextView) 
row.findViewById(R.id.idqty)).setText(cursor.getString(2));
                        tablelayouttransaction.addView(row);

                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

                }

                dbAdapter.close();
                PluCode.getText().clear();
                PluCode.requestFocus();
                displayToast("Data saved");

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I need PluCode refocus again after enterkey pressed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Comment: Try to add `PluCode.requestFocus();` before your last `return true;`. I think that your EditText lost focus with the `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER` and `KeyEvent.ACTION_UP`. Regards

Comment: okay i will try it, and i report soon, thanks Artificioo

Comment: still lost the focus @Artificioo

Comment: Mmm, okay, try changing ACTION_DOWN to ACTION_UP and only return false in this case. In other actions/keys, return true

Comment: @Artificioo thank you so much it's work :D, i change the ACTION_DOWN to ACTION_UP