# How to show and reverse my animation when Edit Text is clicked or tapped?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-animation

My view got 3 item, `EditText`, `ImageView` and `TextView`. now i'm doing some animation base on a tutorial which was working fine, now in that tutorial guy was using `onClickListener` to animate view and hide image, and was working fine, but my problem is, i want to show image when user is not on `EditText` anymore.

Right the idea is working like this

Click on `EditText` => Gonna animate and hide image => and when u tap or click on layout/activity/view/etc. image won't comeback.

Code :

```
    btnInvite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            titleInvite.animate().translationY(-350).setDuration(800).setStartDelay(100).start();
            subtitleInvite.animate().translationY(-350).setDuration(800).setStartDelay(100).start();
            inputInvite.animate().translationY(-350).setDuration(800).setStartDelay(200).start();
            btnInvite.animate().alpha(1).translationY(-350).setDuration(800).setStartDelay(300).start();
            imageView.startAnimation(disapear);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
    });
```

This is what going to happen when someone click on EditText now i want to reverse it when edit text is not focused anymore, or something else clicked. I'm also using API 17, and i'm telling this bcs i looked into some of features but most of them couldn't be used in 17.

Comment: Without looking in your code we can't help much. Add touch listener on root layout

Comment: @PankajKumar, ofc. gonna add it asap.

Comment: @PankajKumar this the code i used. it's just 1 activity 3 object. that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a listener for loosing focus on editText, in that listener execute the reverse animation.

```
EditText txtEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);
txtEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
  @Override public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (!hasFocus) { 
      // Execute reverse animation
    } 
  } 
});
```

Comment: And actually if the animation gas to happen when the textView is focused, you van move the animation code to the same onFocusChange() method

Comment: Thanks. there are 2 problem if i use onClickListener i'm gonna get click sound when i tap on it. and when activity open edit text is focused which gonna do animation on run bcs edit text is focused. and i can't make it false since i'm using api 17(setDefaultFocus is for api 21 above), any idea?

Comment: There are ways to avoid the editText to be selected on activity creation. I suggest you search for them. Heres an example ive used in the past https://stackoverflow.com/a/1662088/3885877