# Android - onFocusChange doesn't work the first time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, focus, onfocuschangelistener

When I touch an `EditText` I want my `scrollView` to scrolls some px. The problem is that it only works when I touch the respective EditText the second time and if the focus was on another editText. Here's the code:

**KOTLIN**:

```
usernameLogin.setOnFocusChangeListener(object: View.OnFocusChangeListener {
     override fun onFocusChange(view:View, hasFocus:Boolean) {
          if (hasFocus){
             scroll_login.scrollTo(0, 240);
          }else{
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lost the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
         }
     }
 })
```

**XML**

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 ...


 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/text_input_usernameLogin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/usernameLogin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:hint="E-mail"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

 </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"/>

 </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your EditText is not focused on default (for example when you switch to this fragment/activity) To prevent this, try to **clearFocus()** on that specific EditText or **requestFocus()** on something else

EDIT: I recently bumped into a similiar post here, hope it helps.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/how-to-stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup-in-android?rq=1)

Comment: Did you try for example forcing focus on to the next EditText and then immediately return focus back to first EditText? something like                                          `myEditText2.requestFocus()
        myEditText2.clearFocus()
        myEditText1.requestFocus()`

Comment: Yes, I've tried. The only away to work the first time is when I request the focus on the second editText, but I don't want it focused by default...

Comment: But you can request focus on the second edit text and just after that request focus on the first edit text again - this way you will reset the focuses but the last focus would be still on the first one. That is if you don't have some onFocusEvents on the second EditText also

Comment: But I don't want anything focused when the activity starts. Sorry for not tellin' you this aspect.

Comment: Hi @qki. I know what the problem is by now, I just can't solve it yet. The problem resides in the system not knowing that we have a scrollView,  because if I call the keyboard when activity starts, it do it what I want.