# scrollview scrolled up when changing a value

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, scrollview

hi every one i have a problem in android studio

when i change a value or move a component , scrollview scrolling to top of the layout and i don't know why!!

here is screenshot

[image: screenshot]

and here is xml:

```
        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_info_workpage"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

              <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">

            ...

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that the modified view is getting focused, and you can stop that by setting the "android:focusable" to false on the view with a value change while setting the same property to true on the parent view.

More Info and sample code in this question and it's answers:
[How to stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/how-to-stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup-in-android)

Comment: thats right but i have any edittexts in my layout and in all my layouts its happen

Comment: The point is that the same applies to some other views when values are changed.